# The inverse of the covariance matrix estimator

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics, covariance

I'm reading a paper, and it says that if $\Sigma$ es the covariance matrix of some random vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^p, X \sim N(\mu_X, \Sigma)$ and $\widehat{\Sigma} = (n-1)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})(X_i-\bar{X})^T$, then $\widehat{\Sigma}^{-1}$ exists with probability $1$. Is there an easy way to prove this? I think that this should use the fact that $\Sigma^{-1}$ exists (since is positive definite), but I think $\widehat{\Sigma}$ is not necessarily positive definite.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use that PCA of $\Sigma$, i.e., $\Sigma  = P \Lambda P^T$, where $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_p)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are the variance of the $i$th PC, and thus $\lambda_i$ are non-negative by definition. Therefore, $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite. For non-degenrate random variables, all $\lambda_i > 0$, for $i=1,...,p$, namely, $\Sigma$ is positive definite matrix. The eigenvalues of $\Sigma^{-1}$ are $1/\lambda_i$ respectively, hence  the inverse matrix is also positive definite matrix.  Same holds for the sample $\hat{\Sigma}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$, where the non-degenerate requirement means that you don't have constant (identical) elements in $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't quite follow the last argument. Where does the 'probability 1' thing come?

Comment: The probability $1$ means, intuitively, that for non-degenerate r.v.s the probability that the sample variance will be $0$ as $n\to \infty$ is $0$, hence w.p $1$, the $\hat{\Sigma}$ is invertible.

Comment: So, for a non-degenerate random variable $X$, there's no $c$ such that $P(X=c)=1$, and that means that $P(\text{var}(X) = 0) = 0$, thus $P(\text{var}(X) \text{ exists} ) = 1$??

Comment: Here $c$ is a constant

Comment: $\exists \hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$ is the same as stating that $ \hat{\Sigma}$ is invertible, which indeed occurs almost surely (as $n \to \infty$).